# Как отправить Get запрос и парсить JSON на java?

Tags: java, json, парсер, maven, gson

Есть ссылка: http://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js
Перейдя по ней Вы увидите следующий код:

```
{
    "Date": "2020-03-07T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousDate": "2020-03-06T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousURL": "\/\/www.cbr-xml-daily.ru\/archive\/2020\/03\/06\/daily_json.js",
    "Timestamp": "2020-03-06T23:00:00+03:00",
    "Valute": {
        "AUD": {
            "ID": "R01010",
            "NumCode": "036",
            "CharCode": "AUD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Австралийский доллар",
            "Value": 44.8181,
            "Previous": 43.8478
        },
        "AZN": {
            "ID": "R01020A",
            "NumCode": "944",
            "CharCode": "AZN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Азербайджанский манат",
            "Value": 39.7981,
            "Previous": 39.0129
        },
        "GBP": {
            "ID": "R01035",
            "NumCode": "826",
            "CharCode": "GBP",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства",
            "Value": 87.5972,
            "Previous": 85.399
        },
        "AMD": {
            "ID": "R01060",
            "NumCode": "051",
            "CharCode": "AMD",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Армянских драмов",
            "Value": 14.0955,
            "Previous": 13.8174
        },
        "BYN": {
            "ID": "R01090B",
            "NumCode": "933",
            "CharCode": "BYN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Белорусский рубль",
            "Value": 30.1592,
            "Previous": 29.5946
        },
        "BGN": {
            "ID": "R01100",
            "NumCode": "975",
            "CharCode": "BGN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Болгарский лев",
            "Value": 38.8411,
            "Previous": 37.6417
        },
        "BRL": {
            "ID": "R01115",
            "NumCode": "986",
            "CharCode": "BRL",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Бразильский реал",
            "Value": 14.6535,
            "Previous": 14.4352
        },
        "HUF": {
            "ID": "R01135",
            "NumCode": "348",
            "CharCode": "HUF",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Венгерских форинтов",
            "Value": 22.5686,
            "Previous": 21.9037
        },
        "HKD": {
            "ID": "R01200",
            "NumCode": "344",
            "CharCode": "HKD",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Гонконгских долларов",
            "Value": 86.8716,
            "Previous": 85.1741
        },
        "DKK": {
            "ID": "R01215",
            "NumCode": "208",
            "CharCode": "DKK",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Датская крона",
            "Value": 10.1709,
            "Previous": 98.5239
        },
        "USD": {
            "ID": "R01235",
            "NumCode": "840",
            "CharCode": "USD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Доллар США",
            "Value": 67.5175,
            "Previous": 66.1854
        },
        "EUR": {
            "ID": "R01239",
            "NumCode": "978",
            "CharCode": "EUR",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Евро",
            "Value": 75.8424,
            "Previous": 73.6842
        },
        "INR": {
            "ID": "R01270",
            "NumCode": "356",
            "CharCode": "INR",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Индийских рупий",
            "Value": 91.8043,
            "Previous": 90.3555
        },
        "KZT": {
            "ID": "R01335",
            "NumCode": "398",
            "CharCode": "KZT",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Казахстанских тенге",
            "Value": 17.6482,
            "Previous": 17.3795
        },
        "CAD": {
            "ID": "R01350",
            "NumCode": "124",
            "CharCode": "CAD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Канадский доллар",
            "Value": 50.4314,
            "Previous": 49.381
        },
        "KGS": {
            "ID": "R01370",
            "NumCode": "417",
            "CharCode": "KGS",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Киргизских сомов",
            "Value": 96.6369,
            "Previous": 94.7167
        },
        "CNY": {
            "ID": "R01375",
            "NumCode": "156",
            "CharCode": "CNY",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Китайских юаней",
            "Value": 97.2861,
            "Previous": 95.3392
        },
        "MDL": {
            "ID": "R01500",
            "NumCode": "498",
            "CharCode": "MDL",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Молдавских леев",
            "Value": 38.8032,
            "Previous": 38.0376
        },
        "NOK": {
            "ID": "R01535",
            "NumCode": "578",
            "CharCode": "NOK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Норвежских крон",
            "Value": 72.8509,
            "Previous": 71.3605
        },
        "PLN": {
            "ID": "R01565",
            "NumCode": "985",
            "CharCode": "PLN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Польский злотый",
            "Value": 17.635,
            "Previous": 17.1518
        },
        "RON": {
            "ID": "R01585F",
            "NumCode": "946",
            "CharCode": "RON",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Румынский лей",
            "Value": 15.7888,
            "Previous": 15.321
        },
        "XDR": {
            "ID": "R01589",
            "NumCode": "960",
            "CharCode": "XDR",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "СДР (специальные права заимствования)",
            "Value": 93.4388,
            "Previous": 91.4259
        },
        "SGD": {
            "ID": "R01625",
            "NumCode": "702",
            "CharCode": "SGD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Сингапурский доллар",
            "Value": 48.8443,
            "Previous": 47.7425
        },
        "TJS": {
            "ID": "R01670",
            "NumCode": "972",
            "CharCode": "TJS",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Таджикских сомони",
            "Value": 69.7423,
            "Previous": 68.3663
        },
        "TRY": {
            "ID": "R01700J",
            "NumCode": "949",
            "CharCode": "TRY",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Турецкая лира",
            "Value": 11.0945,
            "Previous": 10.874
        },
        "TMT": {
            "ID": "R01710A",
            "NumCode": "934",
            "CharCode": "TMT",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Новый туркменский манат",
            "Value": 19.3183,
            "Previous": 18.9372
        },
        "UZS": {
            "ID": "R01717",
            "NumCode": "860",
            "CharCode": "UZS",
            "Nominal": 10000,
            "Name": "Узбекских сумов",
            "Value": 71.1384,
            "Previous": 69.7349
        },
        "UAH": {
            "ID": "R01720",
            "NumCode": "980",
            "CharCode": "UAH",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Украинских гривен",
            "Value": 27.2248,
            "Previous": 26.7627
        },
        "CZK": {
            "ID": "R01760",
            "NumCode": "203",
            "CharCode": "CZK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Чешских крон",
            "Value": 29.8975,
            "Previous": 29.0618
        },
        "SEK": {
            "ID": "R01770",
            "NumCode": "752",
            "CharCode": "SEK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Шведских крон",
            "Value": 71.6815,
            "Previous": 69.7834
        },
        "CHF": {
            "ID": "R01775",
            "NumCode": "756",
            "CharCode": "CHF",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Швейцарский франк",
            "Value": 71.6214,
            "Previous": 69.2026
        },
        "ZAR": {
            "ID": "R01810",
            "NumCode": "710",
            "CharCode": "ZAR",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Южноафриканских рэндов",
            "Value": 43.3274,
            "Previous": 43.149
        },
        "KRW": {
            "ID": "R01815",
            "NumCode": "410",
            "CharCode": "KRW",
            "Nominal": 1000,
            "Name": "Вон Республики Корея",
            "Value": 56.8894,
            "Previous": 55.9575
        },
        "JPY": {
            "ID": "R01820",
            "NumCode": "392",
            "CharCode": "JPY",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Японских иен",
            "Value": 63.777,
            "Previous": 61.7027
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно отправить Get запрос, а затем распарсить JSON.
Необходимо из этого получить значение доллара США и вывести его на экран.
Самая большая проблема, с которой я сталкиваюсь при поиске информации - нигде не говорится, как выводить информацию выборочно (мне не нужно выводить информацию о других валютах, нужна информация только о долларе США)

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема? К слову, процесс преобразования текстовых данных в объект называется десериализацией. После преобразования этого текста в объект получить данные можно как из поля объекта

Comment: @EgorRandomize, проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как мне из этой ссылки извлечь нужные мне данные

Comment: Понял, проблемы две: получение текста по ссылке и интерпретация этого текста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так, метод 100% рабочий:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            Button get;
            TextView answer;
        @Override

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                get = findViewById(R.id.get);     
                answer = findViewById(R.id.answer);

        get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                try {
                                    getHttpResponse();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
        }

         public void getHttpResponse() throws IOException {
         OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
          .build();
         Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url("http://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js")
          .method("GET", null)
          .addHeader("Cookie", "__cfduid=dc5403bef7ac2ab2cb8ead288d39f653e1586600122")
          .build();
          client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
             // если запрос неудачный
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
              // в переменную mMessage получаем ответ
                               final String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                               // Оборачиваем с помощью Runnable textView, т.к. okhttp вызывается в фоновом режиме, а изменение UI возможно только в UI-потоке
                                answer.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
               // Выводим текст в textView
                                        answer.setText(mMessage);
                                    }
                                });

                            }

        // В случае успешного запроса
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
               // в mMessage выводится полученный текст от сервера
                                String mMessage = response.body().string();

                                 try {
                                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mMessage);
                                    JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("Valute");
                                    JSONObject json3 = json2.getJSONObject("USD");

                                    final String TranslationE = json3.getString("Value");

                 // Выводим значение
                                    answer.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            answer.setText(TranslationE);
                                        }
                                    });

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    //
                                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за код и детальное разъяснение
У меня есть несколько вопросов к приведённому Вами коду:
1) Произошла небольшая путаница со скобками, в результате чего метод onResponse оказался внутри метода getHttpResponse(), если я правильно понимаю, нужно их разделить?
2) Какой именно импорт выбрать классу Request? Их несколько.
3) Какой импорт выбрать для класса Response, их просто огромное колличество
4) Что из себя представляет класс OkHttpClient?
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: тут [ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/aleks9090/app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/Main2Activity.java), посмотрите, да, возможно со скобками путаница, но getHttpResponse и OnResponse разделять не нужно. А здесь хороший материал про [OkHttp](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/use-okhttp-to-make-network-requests-on-android-d3845e3c3f50)

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Используйте http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ для преобразования полученного json в POJO.

```
    package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "ID",
        "NumCode",
        "CharCode",
        "Nominal",
        "Name",
        "Value",
        "Previous"
})
public class AMD {

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String iD;
    @JsonProperty("NumCode")
    private String numCode;
    @JsonProperty("CharCode")
    private String charCode;
    @JsonProperty("Nominal")
    private Integer nominal;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Value")
    private Double value;
    @JsonProperty("Previous")
    private Double previous;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public String getID() {
        return iD;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public void setID(String iD) {
        this.iD = iD;
    }

    @JsonProperty("NumCode")
    public String getNumCode() {
        return numCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("NumCode")
    public void setNumCode(String numCode) {
        this.numCode = numCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("CharCode")
    public String getCharCode() {
        return charCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("CharCode")
    public void setCharCode(String charCode) {
        this.charCode = charCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Nominal")
    public Integer getNominal() {
        return nominal;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Nominal")
    public void setNominal(Integer nominal) {
        this.nominal = nominal;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Value")
    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Value")
    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Previous")
    public Double getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Previous")
    public void setPrevious(Double previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Объект этого класса можете использовать для получения нужных вам данных.

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий!

Answer (score 1):

> Пробовал гуглить, но каждый раз сбивает с толку то, что ни в одном
>   примере, из тех, что я видел, не сказано, как работать с ссылкой, по
>   которой расположен код

Это относится уже не к JSON преобразованиям, а работой с сетевыми запросами, в данном случае HTTP запрос на сервер и получение результата с него. Поэтому в примерах вы этого и не встречаете.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Test {
   public static String get(String urlString) throws Exception {
      URL url = new URL(urlString);
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         result.append(line);
      }
      rd.close();
      return result.toString();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
     System.out.println(get("http://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Alex, благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Можно поработать через REST-запросы. Необходимо будет реализовать MVC. Необходимо будет создать контроллеры для POJO-классов и репозитории. Вот Вам официальный гайд(рекомендую читать анг.версию): https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: премного благодарен!